# Is there a way to convert string to binary in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to convert a hexadecimal value to a binary string within a Kusto query, but cannot find any method of doing this in the Kusto documentation / StackOverflow. I see that SQL has this method, but in my case I must use Kusto.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on the scenario and maybe share a small example?

Comment: What is the relevant method in SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kusto's [scalar data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/) do not include binary, bytearray etc.

If I get your intention correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
print hex_str = '48656c6c6f20576f726c64'
| mv-apply c = extract_all('(..)', hex_str) on (summarize str = make_string(make_list(toint(strcat('0x', c)))))
```

| hex_str | str |
| --- | --- |
| 48656c6c6f20576f726c64 | Hello World |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAAzWN0QrCMAxF3wX/IW9NQccYW%20eL3zJC6bTYdqWNMsWPN1NMXg73hpNcfGK4unWqXOAMqj%20ZwVjZuWuH0cxjJ9yr/e4N8XGknMMTrBy6lQtZnigEVNg0Wh3%20Gg1LAqz3GKn4l4OfOdLNba1PF/xy8JWRF/mPEltiVO0qFqu3%20QDJxPZbmQAAAA==)